# how to pass string parameter to SSIS package when executed with SQLCMD

Tags: ssis, sqlcmd

I have a required string project variable
[image]

I need to create the command line to execute this package from Jenkins. This is not working, error message shown:

> The data type of the input value is not compatible with the data type
> of the 'String'.

```
    SQLCMD -S "uat-sql" -Q "Declare @execution_id bigint EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
@package_name=N'xx.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'xx',@project_name=N'xx', use32bitruntime=True, @reference_id=Null 
exec [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'RunType', @parameter_value='regular'
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple, you have to use nvarchar instead.

```
SQLCMD -S "uat-sql" -Q "Declare @execution_id bigint EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
@package_name=N'xx.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, @folder_name=N'xx',@project_name=N'xx', use32bitruntime=True, @reference_id=Null 
exec [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id, @object_type=20, @parameter_name=N'RunType', @parameter_value=**N'regular'**
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
```